# Как взять изменения с другой ветки и при этом удалить свои изменения?

Tags: git

Есть 2 ветки в git, в каждой из которых свои изменения. Как сделать чтобы в моей ветке была полная копия кода с последнего коммита другой ветки (то есть чтобы мои локальные изменения не сохранились)?
Пока получается только слияние моих изменений с изменениями в другой ветке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто удаляем первую ветку, а потом создаем новую на базе второй:

```
git checkout other_branch
git branch -D my_branch
git checkout -b my_branch
```